# text field text in Xcode 9 storyboard off center (and clipping)

Tags: storyboard, textfield, xcode9

Please try the following in Xcode 9 storyboard:

- drag a new text field somewhere in a ViewController
- set some placeholder text
- set border style to none (left dotted one)
- set a background color

I always get the text off center and clipped like this:

[image: clipped text in storyboard]

When I run the app it looks fine vertically centered as it should. Also when you increase the height the text eventually disappears altogether.

Adding a left, top and right constraint helps because it makes the text field's height match the height of the text. The problem with this is the smaller tappable area of the text field.

I couldn't find a mention of this storyboard bug anywhere, how come?

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Anyway, IB is so buggy nowadays that this is a relatively small issue. File a radar.

Comment: Double-click in the text field and then hit enter. Might fix it.

Comment: No luck, sorry. I even tried a brand new project. I know it's not the biggest problem, just annoying.

Comment: I was on 9.0 before and I updated to 9.0.1 but it didn't make a difference. Also I tried it on my colleague's computer, same problem.

Comment: having the same issue :/