# Placeholder text in Xcode doesn't appear on the text field

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

[image]

I am trying to create a login screen for an iOS app, but somehow my placeholder text isn't being recognised by the text field (see the screenshot below). I am really new to iOS.

I tried it on Xcode 8 and it worked but in Xcode 9 somehow it doesn't work.

Did something change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The placeholder text is not shown in Xcode within Interface Builder, but it appears when the app runs, which is all that really matters. (You could file a bug report with Apple complaining about Interface Builder's behavior.)

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826355/text-field-text-in-xcode-9-storyboard-off-center-and-clipping I see this same off-center text in Interface Builder when the placeholder exists.

Comment: Ah thanks because in Xcode 8 I used to see that.Okay now it makes sense. Thanks 